# Additional react dom re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I am working on a frontend for a patient database. I have a table containing some basic information about a patient. When the user clicks on a table row, my DataRowDialogue is rendered as a modal on top. I have three fields in my modal which I want to be able to edit from within my modal. When the user clicks on the edit button, I want to change how the information next to that button is displayed: from span to a TextField (I am using mui at present for styling). However, every time I make a keystroke in the TextField then the focus of the field is lost. Using console.log statements, I have identified that the DataRowCell component is re-rendering but I cannot work out why. Would you be able to help me edit this code so that the DataRowCell is not re-rendered every time I make a keystroke in the TextField

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogActions,
    Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableRow,
    Button, IconButton, TextField
} from '@mui/material';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';
import Datetime from 'react-datetime';
import "react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css";
import moment from 'moment';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PriorityButton from './PriorityButton';
import referrerTypeMapping from './ReferrerTypeMapping';
import formatDate from './FormatDate';
import formatDateTime from './FormatDateTime';
import dataTitles from './DataTitles';
import { fetchReferrals, updateReferral, deleteReferral } from '../../apiHelper';
import formatSpecialty from './FormatSpecialty';

const styles = {
    dialogueBoxCells: {
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        paddingBottom: '30px',
        paddingTop: '30px'
    }
};

const DataRowDialogue = ({ open, onClose, rowData, setReferrals, setSelectedRowData }) => {
    const [editingField, setEditingField] = useState(null);
    const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setEditingField(null)
    }, [onClose]);

    const fetchDataFromAPI = () => {
        fetchReferrals()
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Fetched Data:", data);
                setReferrals(data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("Error fetching data from server: ", err);
            });
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }

    const priorityTextMapping = {
        0: <PriorityButton priority={0} type={1} />,
        1: <PriorityButton priority={1} type={1} />,
        2: <PriorityButton priority={2} type={1} />,
        3: <PriorityButton priority={3} type={1} />
    };

    const modalTitleTextGenerator = (selectedRow) => {
        if (!selectedRow) return "";
        let title = "Medical Referral for " + selectedRow.fname + " " + selectedRow.sname;
        return title;
    }

    const handleEdit = (field) => {
        if (field === 'ptwrTime') {
            setEditValue(moment(rowData[field]));
        } else {
            setEditValue(rowData[field]);
        }
        setEditingField(field);
    };

    const handleClearField = (field) => {
        updateReferral(rowData._id, { [field]: '' })
            .then(() => {
                setReferrals(prev => prev.map(item => item._id === rowData._id ? { ...item, [field]: '' } : item));
                setSelectedRowData({ ...rowData, [field]: '' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("Error updating referral data:", err);
            });
    };

    const handleSaveEdit = () => {
        const updatedData = { ...rowData, [editingField]: editValue };
        updateReferral(rowData._id, { [editingField]: editValue })
            .then(() => {
                setReferrals((prev) => prev.map((item) => (item._id === rowData._id ? updatedData : item)));
                setSelectedRowData(updatedData);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error updating referral data:", err);
            });
        setEditingField(null);
        setEditValue('');
    };


    const handleCancelEdit = () => {
        setEditingField(null);
        setEditValue('');
    }

    const EditTextField = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <TextField
                    value={editValue}
                    onChange={(e) => setEditValue(e.target.value)}
                />
            </>
        )
    }

    const DataRowCell = ({ keyType, value }) => {

        if (keyType === editingField) {
            if (keyType === 'ptwrTime') {
                return (
                    <>
                        <Datetime
                            value={editValue}
                            dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                            timeFormat="HH:mm"
                            onChange={(newValue) => setEditValue(newValue)}
                        />
                        <Button onClick={handleSaveEdit}>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleCancelEdit}>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                    </>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'left', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <EditTextField />
                        <Button onClick={handleSaveEdit}>
                            Save
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleCancelEdit}>
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        } else {
            let displayValue = value;
            if (keyType === 'priority' && priorityTextMapping[value]) {
                displayValue = priorityTextMapping[value];
            } else if (keyType === 'referrerType' && referrerTypeMapping[value]) {
                displayValue = referrerTypeMapping[value];
            } else if (keyType === 'hospitalNumber') {
                displayValue = `RXK${value}`;
            } else if (keyType === 'referralDateTime' || keyType === 'ptwrTime') {
                displayValue = formatDateTime(value);
            } else if (keyType === 'dateOfBirth') {
                displayValue = formatDate(value);
            }

            return (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between', width: '100%' }}>
                    <span>{displayValue}</span>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    const handleDelete = (data) => {
        const confirmation = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (confirmation) {
            deleteReferral(data._id)
            fetchDataFromAPI()
            onClose()
        } else {
            console.log("Delete operation cancelled");
        }
    }

    const EditButton = ({ onEdit, field }) => {
        const handleEditClick = (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            onEdit(field);
        };

        if (['clerkingDr', 'ptwrConsultant', 'ptwrTime'].includes(field)) {
            return (
                <IconButton onClick={handleEditClick} aria-label="edit">
                    <EditIcon />
                </IconButton>
            );
        }

        return null;
    };

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={open}
            onClose={onClose}
            aria-labelledby="row-data-dialog"
            fullWidth
            maxWidth="md"
        >
            <DialogTitle
                id="row-data-dialog"
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    padding: '16px 24px'
                }}
            >
                {modalTitleTextGenerator(rowData)}
                <IconButton
                    onClick={onClose}
                    aria-label="close"
                    style={{ marginLeft: '16px' }}
                >
                    <CloseIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent style={{ padding: '16px 24px' }}>
                <Table size="small">
                    <TableBody>
                        {rowData && Object.entries(rowData).map(([key, value]) => {
                            if (key === '_id') return null;
                            if (key === 'otherReferralLocation' && !value) return null;

                            return (
                                <TableRow key={key}>
                                    <TableCell style={styles.dialogueBoxCells}>
                                        <strong>{dataTitles[key]}</strong>
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell style={styles.dialogueBoxCells}>
                                        {key === 'specialty' ? (
                                            <>
                                                <DataRowCell keyType={key} value={formatSpecialty(value)} />
                                            </>
                                        ) : (
                                            <DataRowCell keyType={key} value={value} />
                                        )}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {['clerkingDr', 'ptwrConsultant', 'ptwrTime'].includes(key) && (
                                            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                                <div title='Edit'>
                                                    <EditButton onEdit={handleEdit} field={key} />
                                                </div>
                                                <div title='Clear contents'>
                                                    <IconButton
                                                        onClick={(e) => {
                                                            e.stopPropagation();
                                                            handleClearField(key);
                                                        }}
                                                        aria-label="clear"
                                                    >
                                                        <ClearIcon />
                                                    </IconButton>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            );
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Link to={{ pathname: `/edit_patient/` }}
                    state={{ object: rowData }}>
                    <Button>
                        Edit
                    </Button>
                </Link>

                <div style={{ width: 5 }} />
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={() => { handleDelete(rowData) }}
                >
                    Delete
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
};

export default DataRowDialogue;
```

Thanks in advance!

I have made rudimentary attempts at utilising useMemo and memo with no success

Comment: No one can compile the code you've included. You should consider making a [mre]